# XML::Compile to generate sample XML from schema with enumeration and choice

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

Following some existing tutorials, I created below perl script to generate XML from xsd.

Script:

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Compile::Schema;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;
use XML::Compile::Util qw/pack_type/;

my $in_qfn  = $ARGV[0];
my $out_qfn = $ARGV[1];

open (OUT, ">$out_qfn") || die "Unable to create output file: $out_qfn\n";

# Generate the hash of xml
my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new($in_qfn);
my $type = pack_type 'urn:testsample','Document';
my $data = $schema->template('PERL', $type);
$data =~ s/#.*//g;
$data =~ s/\s*//g;
$data = eval($data);

# Print the xml
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','UTF-8');
my $write = $schema->compile(WRITER=>$type);
my $xml = $write->($doc,$data);
$doc->setDocumentElement($xml);
print OUT $doc->toString(1);
```

Input Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:testsample" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:testsample" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document">
            <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="address" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="address">
            <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Pname" type="Pname" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element ref="street" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3"/>
                            <xs:element name="contact" type="contacttype"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="contacttype">
            <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="bday" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="email" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="postal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2"/>
            </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Pname">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="AA"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="BB"/>
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="postal" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="bday" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The output is correct. To take it further, in the example schema, there are choice elements, enumerations and repetitive elements. I would like to:

```
1. iterate all the possible values
2. generate maximum repetitive elements, if unbounded then 99
3. generate all choice values
4. split them into multiple XML files such that every XML is valid against the original schema.
```

The output XML files amount is: i*j (i: the amount of choices in each node recursively, can be i1*i2*i3... j: the amount of enumerations in each node recursively, can be j1*j2*j3...)

In this case, it outputs 2*3=6 XML files (if there is an embedded node with 2 enumeration values, then it becomes 2*2*3=12 XML files), similar to:

**XML file 1:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>AA</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:email>example</x0:email>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

**XML File 2:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>BB</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:email>example</x0:email>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

**XML File 3:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>AA</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:bday>2017-10-2</x0:bday>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

**XML File 4:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>BB</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:bday>2017-10-2</x0:bday>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

**XML File 5:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>AA</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:postal>example</x0:postal>
        <x0:postal>example</x0:postal>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

**XML File 6:**

```
<x0:Document xmlns:x0="urn:testsample">
<x0:address>
    <x0:Pname>BB</x0:Pname>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:street>example</x0:street>
    <x0:contact>
        <x0:postal>example</x0:postal>
        <x0:postal>example</x0:postal>
    </x0:contact>
</x0:address>
</x0:Document>
```

I firstly stuck to get the correct value for i and j, as they will be variables used in the generated XML file names, then the possible split. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to build an all-pairs unit test for your schema?

Comment: Yes, that's sort of the idea

Comment: I gave it a second though, maybe modify the XML::Compile module, to give some special value/tag to the enumeration and choice, then split the generated XML. For example: <x0:Pname>AAENUMERATION1</x0:Pname><x0:Pname>BBENUMERATION2</x0:Pname><x0:bday>2017-10-2CHOICE1</x0:bday><x0:postal>exampleCHOICE2</x0:postal><x0:email>exampleCHOICE3</x0:email>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I am the author of XML::Compile)
This can never lead to an generic solution, so it is probably not worth the effort...

Nearly all elements have different values which you need to test, enumeration seems to be special, but isn't.  For instance, an integer is an enumeration as well.  Would you walk all its values?  The number of combinations explode.

When you want to collect more info from the schema than the template() function shows, try to extend XML::Compile::Translate::Template.  It offers you details from the xsd in simple HASH structures.

Success

Comment: I am just reading the Translate, almost there. Thanks for the Answer and the great work on the module!!!

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have a grasp of the size of the numbers involved.

Let me add some limits:

- We limit bounded repetitions to four test cases of `min`, `min+1`, `max-1` and `max` repetitions.
- We limit unbounded repetitions to three test cases of `min`, `min+1` and `min+100` repetitions.
- We always use the same value for `xs:string` and `xs:date`.

Even with those limits, your trivially simple schema would result in 4 × 10<sup>179</sup> combinations (or 4 × 10<sup>19</sup> combinations if we reduce the third case of unbounded repetitions from `min+100` to `min+10`).

To get an idea of the scale of these numbers, consider this: There are only 10<sup>80</sup> atoms in the observable universe.

A generic solution is just not possible.

---

The number was obtained using the following program:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

sub sum { my $acc = 0; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }
sub mul { my $acc = 1; $acc *= $_ for @_; $acc }

sub choice { sum @_ }
sub sequence { mul @_ }

sub repeat {
   my ($x, $min, $max) = @_;
   my @exps;
   if (defined($max)) {
      @exps = ( $min, $min+1, $max-1, $max );
      my $diff = $max - $min;
      die if $diff < 0;
      splice @exps, $diff+1 if $diff < 3;
   } else {
      @exps = ( $min, $min+1, $min+100 );   
   }

   return choice map { $x ** $_ } @exps;
}

# optional($x) is a shortcut for repeat($x, 0, 1)
sub optional { 1 + $_[0] }

sub Document { repeat(address(), 1) }
sub address { sequence optional(Pname()), repeat(street(), 0, 3), contacttype() }
sub contacttype { optional(contacttype_choice()) }
sub contacttype_choice { choice bday(), email(), repeat(postal(), 1, 2) }
sub Pname { 2 }
sub street { 1 }
sub bday { 1 }
sub email { 1 }
sub postal { 1 }

say Document();
```

The above program uses the following simpler-but-equivalent definition of `contacttype`:

```
<xs:complexType name="contacttype">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element ref="bday"/>
                <xs:element ref="email"/>
                <xs:element ref="postal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, you are right, I had modified my script to do non-complete combination of these iterations. i.e.: combination of enums 1, enums 2, etc, as well as the combination of choice 1, choice 2. default maxOccurs 99 (if not specified), default maxLength 399 (if not specified), some other restricts had been set to meet my specific requirement - no guarantee if this logic covers all general cases.

Comment: You did mention those restrictions (except the max length which is impossible to check until after you've dine the work). I used those restrictions and added some restrictions of my own on top of those to get those enormous numbers.